# Dynamically generate string from variable-length set of variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a stored procedure which builds dynamic sql based on metadata tables, and I am experiencing some difficulty.

The major blocker I have run into is the need to dynamically generate a string based on a 'list of variables that would only be established at runtime.

So lets say @a, @b, @c and @d are all defined in the stored procedure. As well as @user and @domain.

The procedure takes @user and @domain and links back to a metadata table containing the set relevant variables for that combination. For @user = 'Josh' and @domain = 1, the results would be:

### |Variables| User | Domain |

### | @a.........| Josh | 1............|

### | @c.........| Josh | 1............|

### | @d.........| Josh | 1............|

Note that this table contains the literal names of the variables, '@a', '@b', etc. It doesn't contain what the variables currently represent.

Right now in the procedure @a = 'I', @c = 'Love', @d = 'Ice Cream'.

Running a cursor over this section of the table, how would it be possible to construct the sentence 'I Love Ice Cream'?

(To be extra cute, lets say @b = 'Do Not'. I am going through this trouble so as explicitly not to include @b, because if I did the string would be a lie.)

Comment: How are you deciding to concatenate `@a`, `@c` and `@d` whilst excluding `@b`?

Comment: The table is a metadata table telling me which are appropriate to use for the user josh

Comment: Does the table contain the values, or just the names of the parameters that you should use? i.e. literally values like `@a`, or values like `Ice Cream`?

Comment: Literally the names of the parameters, otherwise this would be a simple cursor. I will edit the question to make that more clear!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start. And cursors should be avoided almost always. My guess is you don't want or need a cursor here but it is not even remotely clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.  Leave out the bits of the procedure that aren't necessary to illustrate the problem.  In other words, show us what you've tried so far, and then we can perhaps show you how to get to the final goal from there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use `REPLACE()` to replace the variable reference in the string with the variable value.

```
SET @string = REPLACE(@string, '@user', @user)
```

and repeat the same step for each variable.